# Manipulating the attributes of an object when created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to manipulate the attributes of an object when it is created dynamically.

In the code given below, I would like to increase the **like** attribute by calling the corresponding functions of the object. However the elements are created dynamically and passing a **this** in the ***onclick*** function will only refer to the anchor tag.

The idea is similar to this forum wherein each question has various ideas that can be approved or disapproved. How can I manipulate each object's attribute independently?

```
function idea(idea) {
    this.ideatext = idea;
    this.like = 0;
    this.str = "\
    <div class = 'entered'> \
        <div class = 'text'> " + this.ideatext + "</div> \
        <div class = 'anchors'> \
            <a href = '' onclick = 'increase()'> Approve </a> \
            <a href = '' onclick = 'decrease()'> Disapprove </a> \
        </div> \
    </div>";

    this.increase = function() {
        this.like++;
    }
    this.decrease = function() {
        this.like--;
    }
}

var ideaobj1 = new idea(someidea1);
var ideaobj2 = new idea(someidea2);
```

Comment: You will need to somehow tie up the dynamically created elements to the object it is to manipulate.

Comment: Add the element to the document and then select it and modify its attributes, add event handling...

Answer (score 1):

If you dynamically create javascript code and you want it to refer to other javascript code, you have to know the variable names. No way around that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function idea(varName, text)
  {
      this.varName = varName;
      this.ideatext = text;
      this.like = 0;
      this.str = "\
      <div class = 'entered'> \
          <div class = 'text'> " + this.ideatext + "</div> \
          <div class = 'anchors'> \
              <a href = '' onclick = '" + this.varName + ".increase()'> Approve </a> \
              <a href = '' onclick = '" + this.varName + ".decrease()'> Disapprove </a> \
          </div> \
      </div>";

      this.increase = function ()
      {
          this.like++;
          return false;
      }
      this.decrease = function ()
      {
          this.like--;
          return false;
      }
  }

  var wing = new idea("wing", "a wing is ...");
  var wheel = new idea("wheel", "a wheel is  ...");

</script>
```

And use some sort of centralized storage for the created objects. Maybe like this:

```
  var brain = new Object();
  brain["wing"] = new idea("brain.wing", "a wing is ...");
  brain["wheel"] = new idea("brain.wheel", "a wheel is ...");
```

Comment: Alright.. Suppose I create 2 objects - wing and wheel. On the screen, I click wing's **Approve**, how does this refer to the object WING? @Creech

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an onclick attribute, give the  tags a class (I used classes increase and decrease in this example). Then add the following jquery code

```
$(document)
.on('click', '.increase', function() {
    alert('increase function');
});
.on('click', '.decrease', function() {
    alert('decrease function');
});
```

Comment: won't this affect all the objects that has an increase class attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can create elements with the `document.createElement` method:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

And then modify `newDiv` before adding the element to the document.

More info about `document.createElement` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/document.createElement